# Add a subdomain as an exception in hotlinking

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I used this code in my `.htaccess` file and it is working great to prevent hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif|pdf|wav|wmv|wma|avi|mov|mp4|m4v|mp3|zip?)$ - [F]
```

Now I want to allow one of my subdomains (`cdn.example.com`) to access my files using a GET request.

It is not possible to add http_reffer to my GET request! I should only handle it with `.htaccess`.

How should I add my subdomain as an exception in this code?

Comment: "It is not possible to add http_reffer to my GET request!" - What do you mean by this exactly? If the `Referer` header is not being sent as part of the request (for some reason) then you cannot allow this specific hostname, you would need to allow for an _empty_ `Referer` header, which will mean _direct_ requests will also be permitted.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369817/add-subdomain-as-exception-in-hotlinking

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
> ```

Use the following *condition* instead to allow for an optional `cdn` subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://(cdn\.)?\1/
```

(The trailing `.*` is not required.)